# Derivation of the Fokker-Planck equation using characteristic function (expectation of a derivative?)

Tags: probability-distributions, partial-derivative, expected-value

I'm trying to understand a derivation of the Fokker-Planck equation via characteristic functions (specifically from Stochastic Dynamics and Irreversibility by Tânia Tomé , Mário J. de Oliveira, section 3.5 pg. 58), though the question is more about expectations of the derivative of a function and some rearrangements that I don't understand.

$$ik \langle f(x) e^{ikx} \rangle = \langle f(x) \frac{d}{dx} e^{ikx} \rangle = -\int e^{ikx} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} [f(x) P(x)] dx$$

where $\langle \cdot \rangle$ is the expectation of the random variable $x$ with probability distribution $P(x)$.

I'm not really getting the second equality. If I write out the second equality in a way that I know, I would get:

$$\langle f(x) \frac{d}{dx} e^{ikx} \rangle = \int P(x) f(x) \frac{d}{dx} e^{ikx} dx$$

Though something doesn't rub me quite right about what I wrote. It would be great if someone could please help me understand the rearrangement, and why there is the use of the partial derivative. My apologies if this is a simple calculus thing that I don't understand.

The authors also do something similar a few lines down which I assume is a similar trick:

$$-k^2 \langle e^{ikx} \rangle = \langle \frac{d^2}{dx^2} e^{ikx} \rangle = \int e^{ikx} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} P(x) dx$$

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: This looks like integration by parts. Presumably there’s a compact support/decay assumption to get rid of boundary terms.

Comment: The characteristic function is the Fourier transform of the density function. Here, he's just deriving again the fact that differentiation is mapped to multiplication in the Fourier space, i.e. $\mathfrak{F}[\partial_x](k) \equiv ik$ (hence $\mathfrak{F}[\partial_x^2](k) \equiv -k^2$), which is usually proven with the help of integration by parts, as kieransquared mentioned.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much to you both, I understand it completely now.